# Custom acknowledgement in biztalk 2010,

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Need to create an custom acknowledgement similar to biztalk inbuilt 977 acknowledgement.

I am planning to do this in the  `IBaseMessage IComponent.Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)` method.

Is this the correct approach?

Can anyone tell me if there is a better/different approach?

Answer (score 3):

Promote following 2 properties of the Request Message in Receive Pipeline of the Request-Response Receive Location

EpmRRCorrelationToken And RouteDirectToTP

and write or use the custom send pipeline to create the ack as per the need

Refer:
http://niharmalali.blogspot.com/2012/10/acknowledgements-in-biztalk-today-i.html